# How do I convert a MySQL query to codeigniter active records?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I`m new to codeigniter and I would like to convert following MySQL query into Codeigniter Active Record Queries.

**MySQL Query:**

```
select sevadar_id, sevadar_name from tbl_sevadarmaster where  
sevadar_designation = 6 and sevadar_id not in (SELECT p_id FROM  
`tbl_events` WHERE program_id = 27 and event_date = 2014-07-06 and p_id is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has really good docs for their entire API I'd highly suggest giving them a quick read.  Specifically regarding your question you should have a look at the Active Record docs [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) and at the CodeIgniter [query library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html), which will give you tips on producing safer queries using the API.  Together, these two links contain all the API calls you'll need to build your query in CodeIgniter.

At the very simplest level you could do:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select sevadar_id, sevadar_name from tbl_sevadarmaster where sevadar_designation = 6 and sevadar_id not in (SELECT p_id FROM `tbl_events` WHERE program_id = 27 and event_date = 2014-07-06 and p_id is not null)');
```

But you'll want to use query bindings (see the very bottom of the [query libraries](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) page) to auto escape data producing safer queries, here's an example of using query bindings from that page of the API:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?"; 
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

If you use the Active Record library you can try:

```
$this->db->select('p_id');
$this->db->from('tbl_events');
$this->db->where('program_id', 27);
$this->db->where('event_date', '2014-07-06');
$this->db->where('p_id is not', null);
$where_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('sevadar_id, sevadar_name');
$this->db->from('tbl_sevadarmaster');
$this->db->where('sevadar_designation', 6);
$this->db->where("`sevadar_id` NOT IN ($where_clause)", NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: i already tried 
this $query = $this->db->query('select sevadar_id, sevadar_name from tbl_sevadarmaster where sevadar_designation = 6 and sevadar_id not in (SELECT p_id FROM `tbl_events` WHERE program_id = 27 and event_date = 2014-07-06 and p_id is not null)');

but query select all the rows from table, don't know how ?

Comment: Have you tested the inner query, does it return what you want? and if so  can you try splitting up your queries into two and using the results of the inner query within the base query to see if that produces the same result, then we'll know at least what the issue isn't.

Comment: I have tested a query in MySQL Workbench and it works. i am not understanding why the query is not working in code

Comment: ya its woking now by adding ("") double inverted comas to event_date = "2014-07-06".
thanx